# Sending array of information

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I would like to send a couple of arrays to my php with jquery and json, how do i do that?

Im working with:

```
$.ajax(
{
url: "script.php",
type: "POST",
data: ???,
dataType: "html",
success: function(tablehtml){
alert(tablehtml);
}
});
```

Typical i want to send along two arrays, and the php site would then produce a html table.

For instance: i want information about the users `["Tim", "Alan", "Kate"]` for the months `["June", "July", "August"]`

I expect to json_decode in my php script, but how to i pack and send the two arrays? :D

Comment: Your name alone should lead you to the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to decode json on the server side. Suppose you have:

```
var months = ["June", "July", "August"];
var names = ["Tim", "Alan", "Kate"];
```

Then you can use [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to create a serialized representation of them, suitable for sending as a query string, like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "script.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: $.param( { names: names, months: months } ),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(tablehtml){
        alert(tablehtml);
    }
});
```

From PHP, what you'll see is two arrays with keys 'months' and 'names', so, for instance, you can loop over them like this:

```
foreach($_POST['names'] as $name) {
    echo 'Name is: ' . $name . '<br />'; 
}
```

Comment: I believe you don't need `$.param`. Just give the object straight to `$.ajax` and it will convert it for you.

Comment: @box9 - that's correct, if `data` is an object, that's exactly what gets called under the covers.

Comment: @Nick - ah. Hmm, I was under the impression that it needs to be called explicitly to get the brackety representation: `a[]=2&a[]=3&a[]=4`. And it seems the behaviour of $.param is different depending on which version of jQuery is being used.

Comment: that's what the `traditional` setting is for ;), e.g. `traditional: true` on the request, `$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` or `$.param(obj, true);`, but it's jQuery 1.4+ that allows native brackety goodness...in previous versions there's no option, it's all default.

Comment: @Nick - Nice! Thanks for the input. I guess these comments will clear any doubts anyone might have :) And +1 for 'native brackety goodness'! :)

Answer (score 1):

[You can use `JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_JSON_in_Firefox#Converting_objects_into_JSON), like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({users: usersArray, months: monthsArray}),
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(tablehtml){
    alert(tablehtml);
  }
});
```

In this case `usersArray` and `monthsArray` are just the variable names for your already existing arrays. On the PHP side when you deserialize the response, you're just looking for the `users` and `months` properties.

For older browsers that don't support `JSON` natively (IE <8), just [include `json2.js`](http://www.json.org/js.html) and it'll add support...and the above will still work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your arrays are as simple as that, it wouldn't be very difficult to construct a valid JSON string without the use of another library:

```
var json = '{"users":["'+users.join('","')+'"],"months":["'+months.join('","')+'"]}';

$.ajax({
    url: "script.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: json,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(tablehtml) {
        alert(tablehtml);
    }
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't have the effect you're after, since the strings need to be quoted in the array too ;)

Answer (score 0):

send data like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
url: "script.php",
type: "POST",
data:usersArray+'-|-'+monthsArray,
dataType: "html",
success: function(tablehtml){
alert(tablehtml);
}
});
```

In this case usersArray and monthsArray are just the variable names for your already existing JSON arrays.

and then explode that string in php

```
$arr = explode('-|-',$_REQUEST['data'])
```

then

```
$userArray = json_decode($arr[0])

$monthsArray = json_decode($arr[1])
```

i have done this in my project and its running fine

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to stringify your javascript array (serialize a value) using the JSON.stringify (on the json website) and to send it like this :

```
data:"myData="+JSON.stringify(myVar),
```

You will retrieve this value in the $_POST['myData'] and to json_decode it.